# Error:(73, 5) error: illegal start of expression

Tags: database-connection, spinner, android-studio-2.3

anyone can help me?
I'm amateur in android programming.
that's my code:

---

```
package com.example.aleta.dbapp;
/**
 * Created by aleta on 24/07/2017.
 */

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ForSpinner{

     Connection connect;
     PreparedStatement stmt;
     ResultSet rs;
     string srvr,dbn;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState){

         super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.spinners);
         srvr="DESKTOP-F27TAGV\\ALETAYEB_DB";
         db="shop_db";
         spinnerstate=(Spinner)
                 findViewById(R.id.spinnerstate);
             connect=CONN;
           String query="select Title from ostan";

         connect=CONN;
         stmt=connect.prepareStatement(query);
         rs=stmt.executeQuery();
         ArrayList<String> data=new ArrayList<String>();
         while (rs.next()){

             String id=rs.getString("ostan");
             data.add(id);
         }
         String[] array=data.toArray(new String[0]);
         ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,data);
         spinnerstate.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);

         spinnerstate.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

             @Override
             public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id){

                 String name=spinnerstate.getSelectedItem().toString();
                 Toast.makeText(ForSpinner.this,name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT()).show();
             }
             @Override
             public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

             }

         });
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        private Connection CONN(){

            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy((policy));
            Connection conn=null;
            String ConnURL=null;

            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnURL="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + srvr + ";"
                    + "databaseName=" + dbn + ";Integrated security=true;";
            conn=DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);


            return conn;
        }
    }
}
```

---

but an error occurred :

```
Error:(73, 28) error: ';' expected
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2.572 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

how i can solve that?